# Seemingly broken packages on Bower

Tags: javascript, bower

The following packages exist on bower:

bootstrap-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, and angular-ui-bootstrap-bower.

angular-ui-bootstrap-bower seems to be the only one that actually has built js files.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what happens when anyone can register a package in the registry. We can't control what authors chooses to put in a package.